# Angular 8 - how to prompt the browser to "save login" informations, when the login process is divided in 2 steps?

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, input

I created a login portal that we use for many applications.

This is not the standard login form, with 2 `inputs`, one for username and one for password.

It is a single page application, with this structure:

Initial page: `input` field for email

Once the user enters the email and continues, 2 thing can happen:

- email is not valid (we do an API call to check if the email is present in our DB), in this case you get an error message
- email is valid, and now you are presented with multiple buttons, one
  of them is "login with password" (because the user can also login for
  example with Office365, where we redirect the user on Microsoft
  page).
- if "login with password" is chosen, a `input` of `type="password"` is
  now visible

Finally the user presses "login" and if the password is correct, he's now logged in.

This all happens in a single `.html/.ts` file, all done with `ngIf` to show and hide parts.

I want to implement that when the user successfully logs in with the password, the browser will ask if he wants to save the combination of `username + password`, but I don't know how, usually I know it works when both input fields (username and password) are one under the other, but in my case, not sure what to do!

edit: I saw that on Chrome there is a flag to allow : Username-first-flow, which by the description looks like what I want, so there should be a way to implement what I m looking for

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to not save the combination in the browser.
You should instead create a token in your back end upon successful login, then return it to the client, save it in a cookie that has flags secure and samesite to strict.

This token then can be used upon user return to authentify and thus skipping your login process.

Read more on auth process here: https://auth0.com/

Comment: I will look into this as well, but first I would like to see if there is a way to save it in the browser directly, so when the user focuses the email input, it asks him if he wants to use the saved email, and same for when he focuses the password input. Can I achieve that in my app with its structure?

Answer (score 0):

The combination will get saved on a click of a submit button, so if you can like put the username in `localStorage` then when the user chose the password and fill it correctly you simply trigger a submit event but the form has to have the username input and the password input inside of it so this work. Any question?

Comment: once I put the username in localstorage, how do I retrieve it for when the user presses the login button after he inputs the password? And does it need to be a form or I can just have 2 separate FormControl (one for input username, one for input password) ?

Comment: it has to be in the same form in order for the combination to work automatically as i said above. for storing data in local storage: `localStorage.setItem('item_name', yourData.toString())`. For retrieving data do `var myData=localStorage.getItem('item_name')` and from here you can either convert the data to what you want because you can only store strings in localStorage that's why i used toString or you can just leave it.